# Segmentation fault (core dumped) 4

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I keep getting the error Segmentation fault(core dumped) after I use Ctrl+D to stop the input of my program. I have been googling this error and trying to figure out what is causing it, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried googling this problem and looked through other questions/answers on this website, but I still can't figure out why I am getting the error. From my research, I figured out that a segmentation fault error is cause by trying to access memory that I don't have permission to access. I hope this is right.

I am fairly new to C++ and would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"

int main() {

    const int MAX = 100;
    Video *video[MAX];  // up to 100 videos

    for(int l = 0; l < MAX; l++)
    {
        video[l] = NULL;
    }

    string title;
    string url;
    string desc;
    string sorting;
    float length;
    int rate;

    cout << "What sorting method would you like to use?" << endl;
    getline(cin, sorting);
    cout << "Enter the title, the URL, a comment, the length, and a rating for each video" << endl;

    while(getline(cin, title))
    {
        getline(cin, url);
        getline(cin, desc);
        cin >> length;
        cin >> rate;
        cin.ignore();
        for(int k=0; k < MAX; k++)
        {
            video[k] = new Video(title, url, desc, length, rate);
        }
    }


    video[MAX]->print();  // prints the new Video object

    delete[] video[MAX];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `video[MAX]->print()` doesn't make sense, because there is no MAX element in the array.  What did you intend here?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems in your code:

1) Incorrect usage of `delete[]`.

First of all, `delete[]` should be used only to delete dynamically allocated arrays. Yours isn't one.

Second of all, even if video *were* a dynamically allocated array, the correct way to delete it would be

```
delete[] video;
```

The correct way to delete the videos in your code would be to iterate over the array and delete each video:

```
for(int k=0; k < MAX; k++)
{
    delete video[k];
}
```

2) Incorrect indexing of the last element of the array.

```
video[MAX]->print();
```

Should be

```
video[MAX-1]->print();
```

The first element is at index zero, the second one is at index 1... so the last (MAX) element is at index MAX-1.

3) Finally, while not a cause for a segmentation fault, you're probably not trying to fill the entire array with the same video every time you read a line. However, that's what the code does :)

Comment: Addressing your 3rd reason for it not working, would the cause of filling the entire array with the same video be the for-loop that is in the while-loop? Moving this for-loop outside of the while-loop doesn't seem to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Besides the incorrect usage of delete that Danra already pointed out, your array

```
Video *video[MAX];
```

has no element

```
video[MAX];
```

the last element is

```
video[MAX-1];
```

because C++ starts counting with 0 (as you did correctly in your for-loop).
So

```
video[MAX]->print();
```

will fail.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much. Wow :D

Answer (score 0):

```
delete[] video[MAX];
```

tries to array-delete an element beyond the end of video.

You either meant:

```
delete video[MAX - 1];
```

or you mean't

```
delete[] video;
```

Similarly, you might want to review

```
video[MAX]->print();  // prints the new Video object
```

this tries to print the MAX+1th video rather than the last video or the entire list of videos.

You should also review this loop:

```
    for(int k=0; k < MAX; k++)
    {
        video[k] = new Video(title, url, desc, length, rate);
    }
```